# How to transpose a Cython memoryview slice?

Tags: slice, cython, transpose, memoryview, typed-memory-views

I am trying to calculate the transpose of a Cython typed memoryview slice (eg. a 2D part of a 3D array). I am encountering a transpose error specifically when I try to transpose a 2D slice of a 3D memoryview array.

Here is my test code

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
cnp.import_array()
cimport cython

cdef int size_dim1 = 2
cdef int size_dim2 = 2
cdef int size_dim3 = 2

cdef int[:, ::1] arr2D = np.asarray(np.zeros((size_dim2, size_dim3), dtype = np.int32))
cdef int[:, :, ::1] arr3D = np.asarray(np.zeros((size_dim1, size_dim2, size_dim3), dtype = np.int32))

arr2D.T # works fine

arr3D.T # works fine

arr3D[0].T # error
```

The error I get for `arr3D[0].T` is `ValueError: Cannot transpose memoryview with indirect dimensions`.

I found the error in the Cython source code ([source code link](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/d455d51bf31379f47c074e40517e24857d4d9cc0/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L938), line 938) and the error is raised when one of the `.suboffsets` of the memoryview slice is `>=0`. But I checked all of the `.suboffsets` of `arr3D[0]` and they are all `-1` (for the first 2 dimensions). So I don't understand how this error is being raised.

Comment: On a first look that seems like a bug (and so the best thing is to report it on GitHub). It's possible `arr3D[0, :, :].T` might work (but I haven't tested it)

Comment: @DavidW Doing `arr3D[0, :, :].T` gives the same error as above. I'll report it as a bug.

Comment: Thanks - it's possible there's a good reason for it that'll be revealed under close investigation, but it definitely seems like a bug.